# postgres index for "?|" JSONB operator

Tags: postgresql, index, json

I have a jsonb row with objects/dictionairies : {"a":1, "b":2, "c",3}

I want to query rows that contain a set of keys, ex:

```
SELECT * from my_table v 
WHERE v.my_jsonb_column::jsonb ?| array['b','a']
```

how can I create an index for this query ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This index does it :

```
CREATE INDEX my_idx on my_table USING GIN (my_jsonb_column);
```